# Binding div value to event handler

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to bind the `div` value `1` or `2` to implicitly pass it to `getValue` instead of the manual assignments below?

```
<div id="app">
  {{value}}
  <div @click="getValue(1)">1</div>
  <div @click="getValue(2)">2</div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: 'app',
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getValue: (v) => this.value = v
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="app">
  {{value}}
  <div @click="getValue">1</div>
  <div @click="getValue">2</div>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: 'app',
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  methods: {
    getValue: (event) => this.value = event.target.textContent
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the actual content of the div is hardcoded, I guess that the call will be hardcoded too...

You could try:

```
<div id="app">
  {{value}}
  <div v-for="val in values" @click="getValue(val)">{{ val }}</div>
</div>
```

And then:

```
new Vue({
  el: 'app',
  data: {
    value: '',
    values: [1, 2]
  },
  methods: {
    getValue: (v) => this.value = v
  }
})
```